# How can I ensure alphabetical order with json schema of json objects in json arrays?

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

I would like to ensure that json objects within a json array are ordered correctly by a specific property with a json schema.

Is that possible? And if so, how can I create such a json schema?

**Schema:**

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "cities": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "shortName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "showInMap": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "active": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        },
        "??ORDERBY??": "shortName",
        "??ORDER??": "ASC",
        "required": [
           "shortName"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to filter out `json` files which are not correctly ordered.
**Example:** (invalid)

```
{
  "cities": [
    {
      "shortName": "NY",
      "name": "New York",
      "showInMap": true,
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "shortName": "LD",
      "name": "London",
      "showInMap": true,
      "active": false
    },
    {
      "shortName": "MO",
      "name": "Moscow",
      "showInMap": false,
      "active": false
    }
  ]
}
```

And accept `json` files which are ordered correctly.
**Example:** (valid)

```
{
  "cities": [
    {
      "shortName": "LD",
      "name": "London",
      "showInMap": true,
      "active": false
    },
    {
      "shortName": "MO",
      "name": "Moscow",
      "showInMap": false,
      "active": false
    },{
      "shortName": "NY",
      "name": "New York",
      "showInMap": true,
      "active": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is not possible with JSON Schema, however some implementations allow you to add your own custom key words. ajv for example: https://ajv.js.org/custom.html - While this would be fine if you are the only consumer of your schema, it would be pointless if you intend for others to use your schema.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This answer makes no use of `json schema`.

Here is a minimal solution working on your sample data. It is not safe for production, as it is missing all sorts of checks for `undefined`, but I think you can enhance it at will.

```js
function isSorted(array, sortKey) {
  return array.reduce((ordered, item, index) => {
    return index > array.length - 2 ? ordered : ordered && item[sortKey] < array[index + 1][sortKey];
  }, true);
}

const incorrectCase = [{
    "shortName": "NY",
    "name": "New York",
    "showInMap": true,
    "active": true
  },
  {
    "shortName": "LD",
    "name": "London",
    "showInMap": true,
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "shortName": "MO",
    "name": "Moscow",
    "showInMap": false,
    "active": false
  }
]

const correctCase = [{
    "shortName": "LD",
    "name": "London",
    "showInMap": true,
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "shortName": "MO",
    "name": "Moscow",
    "showInMap": false,
    "active": false
  }, {
    "shortName": "NY",
    "name": "New York",
    "showInMap": true,
    "active": true
  }
];

console.log('incorrect case: ', isSorted(incorrectCase, "shortName"));
console.log('correct case: ', isSorted(correctCase, "shortName"));
```

Comment: ok, do I assume correctly that there is no chance to check this sorting with `json schema`? Because you used a method based check instead of `json schema`.

Comment: Seems I have completely missed the point of the question, sorry. Im looking at `json schema` for the first time right now. I will not delete the answer however, just in case someone finds the snippet useful for a method-based check.

Comment: I'm ok with that approach :-). I would have used another language to implement this solution. But I really would like a solution with `json schema`. -.-